# Form does not postback when submit is clicked, jade, node.js

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a form created with jade, it does not postback when submit button is clicked.
I have looked at many similar problems, I tried the solutions, which include ensuring that the input fields all have a 'name', I have made sure all the input field have a name but the form still does not post back, here it is

//views/users/new.jade

h1 New User

form(action="/users", method="POST")

p

label(for="username") Username

input#username(name="username")

p

label(for="name") Name

input#name(name="name")

p
   label(for="bio") Bio

textarea#bio(name="bio")

p
  input(type="submit",value="Create")

The post handler is this

//routes/users

```
module.exports=function(app){

    app.post('/users',function(req,res){
        if(users[req.body.username]){ //Check if user exists
            res.send('Confllict, 409')
        }else
        {
            //add to users list
            users[req.body.username]=req.body;
            res.redirect('/users');
        }
 });
};
```

Comment: perhaps it is a whitespace issue in your jade template. Please edit your post so that the `new.jade` code is in a code block. This will make it easier to debug your issue

Comment: Am not sure what it is since I know little of jade, but perhaps you are right, cuz I just discovered that it works when I get rid of all the 'p' tags, but then I get same problem when I put the p tags back

Comment: I just put back the p tags and removed spaces,you are right, it was the white spaces, thanks

Comment: whitespace has signification meaning in jade. I am guessing the issue with the 'p' tags is indentation issue in `new.jade`. That is why I asked you to edit your post so that the new.jade source code appears as code. As it appears now all the indentation is lost in your post

Comment: I placed back the p tags and got rid of the white spaces, so it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jade uses indention to show what content goes between the tags

```
 p
        this is inside the p tags
```

also there is shorthand

```
p this is also in the tag
```

in your original code you are telling Jade that there is a p tag then the next line is outside the p tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy problem to run into if you aren't careful with indentation using Pug (previously Jade). I realize this is an old question, and it has several hits so perhaps this answer will shed some light for new Pug users.

The problem with the OP's code is the Form does not know how to post without a button, and the Submit button doesn't know where to post to without being associated with the Form. Why? Indentation.

Jade and Pug tips for success:

1. They produce html, so it helps to think in html layouts when developing the template (would you put text outside of your p element? Of course not).
2. Pug uses indentation to form layout and element hierarchy.
3. Html Forms must **enclose** the elements that are to be associated or bound to it.
4. A Submit Button does nothing unless you define an event handler.
5. Forms define a destination in their definition, which a button type element can leverage.

In the code listed by the OP, every Pug element is left-aligned. This puts all elements at the same level, so there is no hierarchy or nesting. Since there is no other event handler explicitly defined for the Submit button, nothing happens when it is clicked, despite the form having an action and a valid method.

To fix this, the Input (submit button) can be nested inside the Form.

Reworking the code to include indented hierarchy will enable the POST to function as expected (removed all the other elements for readability):

```html
h1 New User
form(action="/users", method="POST")
    label(for="username") Username
    input#username(name="username")
    label(for="name") Name
    input#name(name="name")
    label(for="bio") Bio
    textarea#bio(name="bio")
    input(type="submit",value="Create")
```

The resulting form won't be a pretty, but it will function:

- The Form has an action and method.
- All dependent elements are indented.
- The input has a type of Submit and is child to the form.

Of course, a server must have a binding at the address to receive the data in order to do anything with it.